# Html standard helper is null from within custom helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have some custom helpers made using @helper inside a .cshtml helper like this:

```
@helper MyCustomField(string value, bool valueAsRaw)
{
    <div>
        @if (valueAsRaw)
        {
            @Html.Raw(value)
        }
        else
        {
            @value
        }
    </div>
}
```

When I run this, I get null value exception on the @Html helper object. How can I access the standard HtmlHelper methods?

In VS, I get intellisense on the Html.Raw, so it is available, but it is null at run time.

Answer (score 0):

May be your accessing the helper method incorrectly . 
Used your code and it's working as expected.

View.cshtml

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  @MyCustomFiled("StackOverFlow",true)
</td>
</tr>
</table>

@helper MyCustomFiled(string value, bool valueAsRaw)
{
    <div>
        @if (valueAsRaw)
        {
            @Html.Raw(value)
        }
        else
        {
            @value
        }
    </div>
}
```